# Git merge only the diff between two branches

Tags: git

Say I have `branchA` with the latest features and then I have the `branchB`which has the hotfixes not yet sync into `branchA`.

What I want to do is merged all hotfixes into that latest features (`branchA`) but only the diff.
I saw that `git log branchA..branchB` actually shows the commits in `branchB` not yet existing in `branchA`. Unfortunately I don't know the command how to merged the `branchB` diff commits into `branchA`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're very close. You can do it as a patch:

```
git diff branchA..branchB > mypatch.patch
```

Then apply the patch to the desired branch:

```
git apply mypatch.patch
```

Comment: Weird , its merging everything :(

Comment: I got it now, i think this is the correct answer `git diff branchA...branchB > mypatch.patch`

Comment: Cool, we were both really close @david!

Comment: This fuse (not merge) the commits history with a re-authored single change that will not conflict with that specific history, but I would never `git apply` a patch/difference that is already in the repository, in general.
If someone else come to this question consider `git merge branchB` from branchA, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase` which might be more appropriate than pipe a `git diff` to `git apply`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to apply changes from branch X to current branch:

```
git diff ..X | git apply -
```

This is simply a shorter version of the accepted answer.

Comment: Very handy! Works very well